# Incorrect usage of stategy pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Is the following an incorrect usage of the strategy

```
interface FilterStrategy {
  public void filter();
}

class OldProductsStrategy implements FilterStrategy {
  public filter();
}

class NewProductsStrategy implements FilterStrategy {
  public filter();
}

class ProductsFilterStrategy {
  public getFilter(a) {
   if(a) {
     return new NewProductsStrategy();
   } else {
     return new OldProductsStrategy();
   }
}

class Client {
  new ProductsFilterStrategy().getFilter(true).filter();
}
```

Is delegating the selection of the strategy implementation part of the strategy pattern?

Comment: If the value you are passing into `getFilter` is determined at runtime - then I don't see any issue with it whatsoever. If it isn't, doing this can potentially be a little redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The usage is fine. But technically  the class which is responsible of creating different instances is a factory. Not part of the strategy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how to adopt the pattern. But there is many advantages in keep the pattern way in mind when adopting and implementing the pattern.

Based on the pattern definition you should have a Context class that:

1. is configured with a ConcreteStrategy object
2. maintains a reference to a Strategy object
3. may define an interface that lets Strategy access its data.

So that you can provide a usage like this:

```
  context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyA());
  context.ContextInterface();

  context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyB());
  context.ContextInterface();

  context = new Context(new ConcreteStrategyC());
  context.ContextInterface();
```

You can provide the strategy instance using a factory or IoC container. It is not part of Context.

Answer (score 0):

Example is valid code to provide Strategy hierarchy through static factory. Which looks fine. Only class representing *Context* in strategy pattern is missing in the above code.

If the Strategies are stateless why to create new strategy every time, those can be shared from pool.